# VS Code not recognising module aliases in Expo project

Tags: visual-studio-code, expo

I've set up import aliases in my Expo project. It's compiling fine however VS Code doenst recognise the import:

In tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "home": ["./"]
    }
  }
}
```

In babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            home: "./"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
};
```

The import in the file works: `import Thing from "home/src/thing";`

I thought this would make VS Code aware of the alias but it appears not to do anything

In jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "home/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `jsconfig.json` *and* a `tsconfig.json`? If I am not mistaken, you can only use one and `tsconfig.json` will be preferred.

Comment: I thought that this was needed for VS Code?

Comment: If you have a TS project, choose `tsconfig.json` (for a hybrid, you can set `allowJs`), for JS only `jsconfig.json`.